# I am trying to retrive records from h2 databse using rest controller but its says no data set

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

****Here is my code for springboot application which shows error No datasource set****...........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
server.port=8081
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
 
# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

controller

```
package com.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.daoimpl.ProductDaoImpl;
import com.service.ProductService;

import pojo.Product;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {


    //ProductService productservice;
    ProductDaoImpl pdi=new ProductDaoImpl();
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/products", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Product>getAllProducts()
    {
        System.out.println("in controller");
        //return pls.productListAllRecords();
        return pdi.productListAllRecords();
    }
    

}
```

Daoimpl

```
package com.daoimpl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.dao.ProductDao;

import pojo.Product;

@Component
@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jtemp=new JdbcTemplate();
    String GET_ALL_RECORDS="SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_REGISTER";

    public class ProductRowMapper implements RowMapper<Product>{

        @Override
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Product pro =new Product();
            pro.setProductUniqueId(rs.getInt("product_unique_code"));
            pro.setProductName(rs.getString("product_name"));
            pro.setProductCategory(rs.getString("product_category"));
            pro.setProductSubCategory(rs.getString("product_sub_category"));
            pro.setBrand(rs.getString("product_brand"));
            pro.setProductWeight(rs.getInt("product_weight"));
            pro.setProductPrice(rs.getInt("product_price"));
            
            
            return pro;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public List<Product> productListAllRecords() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hehehhe");
        
        List<Product> pross= jtemp.query(GET_ALL_RECORDS,new ProductRowMapper());
        return pross;

        
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dhooms-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dhooms-2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.193</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

error in console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.4.0-SNAPSHOT)

2020-07-21 10:34:34.754  INFO 4804 --- [           main] com.a.Dhooms2Application                 : Starting Dhooms2Application using Java 11.0.7 on DESKTOP-H9FM8Q7 with PID 4804 (C:\Users\siddhesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE\dhooms-2\target\classes started by siddhesh in C:\Users\siddhesh\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.7.0.RELEASE\dhooms-2)
2020-07-21 10:34:34.758  INFO 4804 --- [           main] com.a.Dhooms2Application                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-21 10:34:35.935  INFO 4804 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-07-21 10:34:35.959  INFO 4804 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-21 10:34:36.355  INFO 4804 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84228bcc] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-07-21 10:34:36.440  INFO 4804 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-07-21 10:34:37.011  INFO 4804 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2020-07-21 10:34:37.024  INFO 4804 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-07-21 10:34:37.025  INFO 4804 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-07-21 10:34:37.235  INFO 4804 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-07-21 10:34:37.236  INFO 4804 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2396 ms
2020-07-21 10:34:37.345  INFO 4804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-07-21 10:34:37.529  INFO 4804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-07-21 10:34:37.621  INFO 4804 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2020-07-21 10:34:37.993  INFO 4804 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-21 10:34:38.072  INFO 4804 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-07-21 10:34:38.157  INFO 4804 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.18.Final
2020-07-21 10:34:38.160  WARN 4804 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-07-21 10:34:38.695  INFO 4804 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-07-21 10:34:39.068  INFO 4804 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-07-21 10:34:39.662  INFO 4804 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-07-21 10:34:39.679  INFO 4804 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-21 10:34:40.048  INFO 4804 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2020-07-21 10:34:40.051  INFO 4804 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-07-21 10:34:40.052  INFO 4804 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-07-21 10:34:40.083  INFO 4804 --- [           main] com.a.Dhooms2Application                 : Started Dhooms2Application in 5.896 seconds (JVM running for 8.231)
2020-07-21 10:34:54.597  INFO 4804 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-21 10:34:54.597  INFO 4804 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-21 10:34:54.598  INFO 4804 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
in controller
hehehhe
2020-07-21 10:34:54.795 ERROR 4804 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DataSource set] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DataSource set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.obtainDataSource(JdbcAccessor.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at com.daoimpl.ProductDaoImpl.productListAllRecords(ProductDaoImpl.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.controller.ProductController.getAllProducts(ProductController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:890) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:804) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1062) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

You created the JdbcTemplate instance using new keyword, which is like working outside Spring dependency injection, and therefore will not have the DataSource injected. Please update this in your code

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jtemp=new JdbcTemplate();
```

to

```
@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: First of all thanks for takeing the time and answering the question, I did as u said but cam across the new error java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Looks like you have a similar problem on the line where you should be injecting the DAO.

ProductDaoImpl pdi=new ProductDaoImpl();

Should also be setup to @Autowired private ProductDAO pdi;

Comment: @navid mitchell tried that aswell  heres what i get:-Description:

Field pdi in com.controller.ProductController required a bean of type 'com.daoimpl.ProductDaoImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.daoimpl.ProductDaoImpl' in your configuration.

Comment: Do you have this code available in GitHub. I think you have a problem with your spring config.

Comment: Your Spring Application main class should have something similar to the following. 

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.controller", "com.service"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.daoimpl"}) 
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"pojo"})

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend following a standard java package structure so maybe something like.

com.myapplication
com.myapplication.controllers
com.myapplication.services
com.myapplication.daos
com.myapplication.pojos

Comment: @navidMitchell  here is the github repository link [https://github.com/siddheshvesit/experiment.git ] which works fine coz everything is undersame package but when i split files in diffrent package it throws null pointer exception

Comment: This is because by default the @SpringBootApplication will only scan packages under the same package as the app definition. So in your case you can leave Railwaybokking1Application in com.example.demo then put your controllers in say com.example.demo.controllers and do the following for the rest of your separation making sure all of your packages begin with com.example.demo . If you want to use a different structure you will have to use the other annotations I listed in the previous comment.

Comment: @NavidMitchell Thanks for the suggestion it resolved my issue improper package name was the issue ur suggestion solved it thanks....:)